# airflow db init doesn't create an expected "airflow" directory on windows

Tags: database, windows, airflow, virtualenv, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using windows, and accessing WSL through VSCode

I am currently learning airflow and ran into an issue with the command `airflow db init`. According to a tutorial I'm following, there should be a new directory called `airflow` inside the current directory, but it is not there

My current path is `(sandbox) nick@GameCube:/mnt/d/CodeAndIDE/DataScience/LearnAirflow$`. I am using a venv called "sandbox"

When I run `airflow db init`, it outputs a bunch of lines, which match the tutorial, but no folder is created after. No error output either. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

I **partially** figured out the solution. You have to first set the airflow home directory to the current folder, with `export AIRFLOW_HOME="$(pwd)"`.

For some reason, this didn't create a directory for the file and just dumped them all into the main directory, so I deleted them all and did `mkdir airflow`, `cd airflow`, `export AIRFLOW_HOME="$(pwd)"` again.

The last problem that I'm having is that `unittests.cfg` is not present in the folder, when I think that it should be